# Norm MPEG-1 Layer III (Mp3) Filter banks distortion

Tags: filter-bank, distortion, mp3

So, I'm working with the filter banks used in Mp3, in Matlab. I am obtaining quite a huge distortion in the output and I don't really know whether I'm making something wrong.

I've reviewed the literature and I'd say I'm making it properly, so I don't really understand what I'm making wrong.

So I'm basing the work on a filter with 512 coefficients that can be found on page 9-13, here: https://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/docs/jacaba_main.pdf (I think it comes from a standard so no big deal there, I guess).

I want to make a filter bank with 32 branches. I want to, based on that Low Pass filter prototype, calculate the 32 branches that will cover the entire bandwidth, so I make:

(note "h" is the variable with the filter coefficients)

```
branches=32;
hh=zeros(branches-1,length(h));
n=0:511;
for k=0:1:branches-1 
   hh(k+1,:)=h.*cos(((2*k+1)*pi*(n-16))/(2*32));
end
```

That one for the generation of the analysis filters coefficients and the following one for the synthesis filters:

```
branches=32;
hh=zeros(branches-1,length(h));
n=0:511;
for k=0:1:branches-1 
   hh(k+1,:)=h.*cos(((2*k+1)*pi*(n+16))/(2*32));
end
```

As per the way of applying the filters to the input signal and to reconstruct the output signal:

```
yy=zeros(branches,floor(length(wav_in)/32)+1)
for k=1:1:branches
  yy(k,:)=decimate(filter(hh(k,:),1,wav_in),branches);
end
```

This will provide a matrix with all the outputs of the shifted analysis filters (`yy`).

Now, in order to reconstruct the signal, with the synthesis filters:
(Note it's a different function so we will not have problems with the variables names)

```
yy = zeros(1,length(xd(1,:))*32)
for k=1:1:branches
  yy=yy+(filter(hh(k,:),1,upsample(xd(k,:),branches)));
end
```

The filter responses look good (it seems like that to me, at least):
[image: Analysis Filter bank response]

[image: Synthesis Filter bank reponse]

If I use as an input a 1 kHz tone, I have:

[image]

The output is "After". As you can see the signal is very distorted. In general, I am following the approach in "How sound is processed in MP3 player?" by T. Dutoit and N. Moreau.

I think it is not working and honestly, I don't have a single clue on what I'm doing wrong. (Maybe how I'm applying the filter banks?).

Comment: Can you please also post the low-pass protoype filter impulse response coefficients ? As it's hard to copy from the pdf document and i don't want to use a homemade filter there...

Comment: Hi!
Sure, you can grab the mat file from here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3aZza3bav9gWWwwSEpYNGgxTE0

Comment: Can you edit your source code to omit redundant/confusing parentheses? `cos(((((2*k+1)*pi*(n-16))/(2*32))))` is plain bad code. Same goes for things like doing a convolution of complicated expressions just to get its length. The convolution of two sequences has a defined length, and there's no reason to actually first upsample something to a defined length, and then convolve it with something of a defined length, just to calculate `length()` of that. I'll have to ask you to make your code acceptably well-written before asking about it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MarcusMüller. 

As per the coise content , I'll update it.
As per the length of the convolution. You are right, I was kind of lazy there. 
BTW: Although the length of a conv. of two sequences has a defined length (the sum of both lengths -1), filter function makes length(out)=length(in).

Comment: So, this can make the length line easier: yy=zeros(1,length(xd(1,:))*32)

Anyway, you are right: the code shall always be as readable as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code.

There are problems with the **decimation** and **upsample** stages. When you run the analysis and synthesis filters at the undecimated rate, then you get the perfect reconstruction (plus a filter shift)

First of all in case of applications which are sensitive to group delay, you should better use the **conv / filter** function and then **compansate** for the group delay.

Also, the **decimate** function applies a **lowpass** anti-aliasing filter, which kills the signal content at the $k$-th channel considering the fact that its output is a bandpass signal rather than lowpass. Hence you should **avoid** the anti-aliased decimation but instead employ a bandpass decimation strategy.
A direct subsampling by 32 would provide a convincing result.

Same goes with **interpolation** part. After you expand your signal, you should select the proper band of image spectrum by a suitable bandpass filter, rather than a lowpass filter from a conventional interpolator. A direct expansion may convince as its output will already be bandpass filtered later by the polyphase filterbank.

That being said, your **main** problem is the **document** that you based your code. That's far too out of signal processing context. I suggest you read the MPEG audio standard book of BOSI. But it's up to you of course.

The following is a **working** corrected MATLAB / OCTAVEcode:

```
% S0 - Load the prototype lowpass filter impulse response:
% --------------------------------------------------------
load h2.mat;         % h[n] is the prototype lowpass filter... of length 512
L = length(h);

figure,subplot(2,1,1)
stem([0:L-1],h);title('The Prototype Lowpass Filter');
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(linspace(-1,1,4*L),20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(h,4*L)))));
grid on;


% S1 - Create the 32 band filter bank by cosine modulation
% --------------------------------------------------------
numbands = 32;                  % number of bands
n=0:L-1;

hha=zeros(numbands,L);         % band of filters
for k=0:1:numbands-1 
   hha(k+1,:) = h.*cos( ( (2*k+1)*pi*(n-16) ) / (2*numbands) );
end

figure
plot(linspace(-1,1,4*L),20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(hha(1,:),4*L)))));
title('ANALYSIS FILTER BANK');
hold on
for k=1:numbands
    plot(linspace(-1,1,4*L),20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(hha(k,:),4*L)))));
end

% S2 - Design the synthesis filterbank:
% -------------------------------------
numbands = 32;                     % number of banks
n=0:L-1;

hhs = zeros(numbands,L);           % band of filters
for k=0:1:numbands-1 
   hhs(k+1,:) = h.*cos( ( (2*k+1)*pi*(n+16) ) / (2*numbands) );
end


% S3 - Generate a test input signal:
% ----------------------------------
N = 2*1024;      % NOTE: According to the MPEG specification a determined LENGTH must be applied.
wav_in = sin(0.05*pi*[0:N-1]);        % pure sine tone

figure,subplot(2,1,1)
plot(wav_in);title('input signal')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(linspace(-1,1,4*N),20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(wav_in,4*N)))));


% S4 - Apply a wav file to it,  get every output of the every sub-band:
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
yyd = zeros( numbands, floor(N/numbands));   % decimated outputs..
yyu = zeros( numbands , N);

for k=1:1:numbands
    temp = conv( wav_in,hha(k,:));
    yyu(k,:) = temp(L/2+1:L/2+N);
    yyd(k,:) = yyu(k,1:numbands:end);
end


% S6 - Apply synthesis on the decimated signal
% --------------------------------------------
ys = zeros(1, N);
yi = zeros(1,N);

for k=1:1:numbands
    yi(1:numbands:end) = yyd(k,:);
    temp = conv(yi,hhs(k,:));
    ys = ys + temp(L/2+1:L/2+N);
end
ys = numbands*ys;

% Display the result:    
figure,subplot(2,1,1)
plot(ys);title('Synthesized Back');
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(linspace(-1,1,4*N),20*log10(abs(fftshift(fft(ys,4*N)))));
```

With the outputs being:

1- The prototype filter:

[image]

2- 32 channel filter bank:

[image]

3- A pure tone input:

[image]

4- An reconstructed back output:

[image]

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

I was killing the signal with the LPF in the decimate part.
Now it works. Thanks a lot for the rest of the comments.